# How can we hide Navigation Blur in UIKit for VisionOS?

Tags: swift, visionos

How can we hide this native blur effect behind our navigationBar? I cant find an approach without hiding the navigation bar itself. I want to maintain the navigationBar but just remove he blue.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
let cellId = "CellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
  
    navigationItem.title = "Testing"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}
}
```

[image]